# "That" usage: when should I point something using "that"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

When should I use "that" explicitly and when I can imply it? For example, I'm describing some circumstances and I need to point something in this description:

> This means **that** a street name was written with several mistakes.

or

> This means a street name was written with several mistakes.